# How to remove both number and text from a parenthesis using regrex in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

In the following text, I want to remove everything inside the parenthesis including number and string. I use the following syntax but I got result of 22701 instead of 2270. What would be a way to show 2270 only using re.sub? Thanks

```
import regex as re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

text = "2270 (1st xyz)"
text_new = re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z()\s]","",text)
text_new
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the text always follow the same pattern? Try:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

text = "2270 (1st xyz)"
text_new = re.sub(r"\s\([^)]*\)","",text)
print(text_new)
```

**Output:**

```
2270
```

Comment: Thanks mr_mooo_cow, in my real data, there are lots of text that does not follow the same pattern. may I ask what does the combination of [^)]*\ inside the parenthesis do?

Comment: @user032020 First, you are asking about ```[^)]*\```, but the last ```\``` is there to escape the special character `)`. So it's actually just `[^)]*`. It basically means match anything between the `()` *except* `)`, which is why the `^` is there.

Comment: What Ann Zen said. Pretty much the idea is-- delete everything inside and including the parentheses and the space in between.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the regex pattern `\(.*?\)`:

```
import re

text = "2270 (1st xyz)"
text_new = re.sub("\(.*?\)", "", text)
print(text_new)
```

Output:

```
2270
```

Explanation on the pattern `\(.*?\)`:

- The `\` behind each parenthesis is to tell `re` to treat the parenthesis as a regular character, as they are by default special characters in `re`.
- The `.` matches any character except the newline character.
- The `*` matches zero or more occurrences of the pattern immediately specified before the `*`.
- The `?` tells re to match as little text as possible, thus making it non-greedy.

---

Note the trailing space in the output. To remove it, simply add it to the pattern:

```
import re

text = "2270 (1st xyz)"
text_new = re.sub(" \(.*?\)", "", text)
print(text_new)
```

Output:

```
2270
```

Comment: Thanks Ann. May I ask beside the ?, what does the . and * and \ means inside the parenthesis?

Comment: @user032020 My pleasure! I have updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thanks Ann for all your detail explanation. I will take  mr_mooo_cow's approach as a solution because it also moves the white space after 2270 but your advice and helps are really appreciated!

Comment: @user032020 I'm glad! By the way, you can simply add the space like so `text_new = re.sub(" \(.*?\)", "", text)`. See my updated solution.